# convert [Dictionary<String,Any?>] to [Dictionary<String,Any!>] ? swift 3

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

I am trying to append `[Dictionary<String,Any!>]` to `[Dictionary<String,Any?>]`

but I keep getting this Error:

> Cannot Convert value of Type [Dictionary] to expected argument type of [Dictionary]

Although I didn't get this compile error with `swift2` .

Here is my code:

```
class A{

     var statistics = [Dictionary<String,Any!>]();

     func1(){


       let oldStatiscs = self.func2()
       //i am getting the error here.
       self.statistics.append(oldStatiscs)


    }

    func2 () -> [Dictionary<String,Any?>]{


   }

}
```

Why am I getting this error on swift3? Why don't I get this error with swift2?
How can this problem be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Any optional value in a Swift – in Objective-C it's even not allowed –  dictionary is nonsensical, because by definition a `nil` value means a missing key and you can remove a key by assigning a `nil` value.

Comment: @vadian thank you for your comment, yes i know , but currently i can't change  it to Dictionary<String,Any> . do have any solution for my problem ?

Comment: `[Dictionary<String,Any!>]` is illegal in Swift 3 as a variable type (it can only exist in a small number of places). You must change it. If you can't change it, you cannot upgrade to Swift 3. You're not seeing the errors yet, but if you fix all the other bugs, you'll finally run into "Implicitly unwrapped optionals are only allowed at top level and as function results." You cannot use this type any more (it was nonsense in Swift 2; it's illegal in Swift 3).

Comment: @david Why can't you change `Dictionary<String,Any?>` to `Dictionary<String,Any>`

Comment: @maddy thank you for your answer, because in my code may i append nil value, i can't now go through all my thousands cases to make sure no nil appended. i don't understand why apple changed this in swift 3 ?

Comment: It would help if you posted an example showing how you append a nil value in your Swift 3 code.

Comment: @maddy , it's simpel , i have several functions which receive several variables and append it to the dictionary. those variable may be nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, even if you change both arrays of dictionaries to `[Dictionary<String,Any>]` you still get a similar error. You are trying to append an array to an array. So you first need to change:

```
self.statistics.append(oldStatiscs)
```

to:

```
self.statistics.append(contentsOf: oldStatiscs)
```

But even with that change, you can't append an array of `[Dictionary<String,Any?>]` to an array of `[Dictionary<String,Any!>]`.

The simplest solution is to change the `[Dictionary<String,Any!>]` array to an `[Dictionary<String,Any?>]` array.

Then you end up with the following working code:

```
class A {
    var statistics = [Dictionary<String,Any?>]();

    func f1() {
        let oldStatiscs = self.f2()
        statistics.append(contentsOf: oldStatiscs)
    }

    func f2() -> [Dictionary<String,Any?>] {
        return [["Hi":"There"]]
    }
}
```

Even better is to get rid of `Any?` and use `Any`.

```
class A {
    var statistics = [Dictionary<String,Any>]();

    func f1() {
        let oldStatiscs = self.f2()
        statistics.append(contentsOf: oldStatiscs)
    }

    func f2() -> [Dictionary<String,Any>] {
        return [["Hi":"There"]]
    }
}
```

You need to explain why you think you can't change `Any?` to `Any`.